# ViewBag instead of IEnumerable in DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, ienumerable, viewbag

I have a ViewBag passed in consisting of IDs and Titles from a class (we will call it Games). I am trying to make an Html.DropDownList using the contents of the ViewBag instead of an Enum.

Right Now, I have the following code which is incorrect:

```
Html.DropDownList("GameID", new SelectList(from IEnumerable<Games> game in 
Enum.GetValues(ViewBag.Games) select new { value = 
ViewBag.Games.ID, name = ViewBag.Games.Title}, "value", "name", Model.Content.GameID))
```

I know that I need to replace the from and the in variables but I do not know what to replace them with. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833257/asp-net-mvc3-dropdownlist-and-passing-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have the Game's ID and Title fields being past down in the ViewBag, why could you not just do this?

```
@Html.DropDownList("GameID", new SelectList(ViewBag.Games, "ID", "Title"))
```